# How to redirect the User From Browser to Application in iOS?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

i am newbie in iOS Development i make an application that show Bollywood news.for that i make a table view that contain News Head line and when UITableViewCell was selected then redirect to browser for reading news.that works fine.and here all data is JSON Data.

i write a code for that is:-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   NSDictionary *dictionary=[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
   NSString *url=[dictionary valueForKey:@"link"];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
 }
```

here Dictionary key is "link" and it contain url it work fine and url is open in to my Simulater Browser,But Problem is that how to redirect user from Browser to application when user want to back. if any solution possible? then please help me

Comment: As per your application requirement you should implement UIWebView in your application to show the web content user selected. It is like Master-Detail Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the link in your app will open a new web browser application meaning you have no control over it and can't add your own buttons or links.

However, if you are the webmaster of the site that has been opened, you can [create and use custom url schemes](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

I don't think this is the case for you though so the next best solution I can think of is instead of opening the link in a new web browser application, get it to open itself in a `UIWebView` inside your application. Then you can add buttons, links, navigation bars, etc..

---

Basics of how to add a `UIWebView`

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];  //Change self.view.bounds to a smaller CGRect if you don't want it to take up the whole screen or use autolayout
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_LINK_URL"]]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: #Hodson then how can i add UIWebView please give me any solution.

Comment: @AshishGabani - I've added some basic code on how you can programmatically add a `UIWebView` to an app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there may be one solution.
You must register your application's Custom URL Scheme and place link to it on your web page.
You can read more e.g here: http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

Comment: #Michal Banasiak how do it i am confuse i not understand what they say lpease you can give me some basic code for that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way for this. Worst, the documentation of `UIApplication` `-openURL:` method says :

> The URL can locate a resource in the same or other app. If the
>   resource is another app, invoking this method may cause the calling
>   app to quit so the other one can be launched.

If you want to do it, then don't call `-openURL:`, push a `webView` to present the URL content, and provide a back button to get back to your tableview.

Comment: If you have control over webpage contents, then Michal Banasiak's answer is a good one.